# Responsive web design and media queries for iPad Portrait not showing any changes when re-sizing window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am looking to add some responsive web design to my site for iPad Portrait. I have my main css file (style.css) and then i have added the line below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad-portrait.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)" />
```

However when i try to set a div's background colour to red or something then resize the window i cannot see any change when it gets to the iPad Portrait size.

The stylesheet im linking to looks like:

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */

.myTile{background:red;}

}
```

I have tried it with and without this and no difference when i resize.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be great, I am just picking up responsive design.

Thanks

Comment: what browser / version are you using?

Comment: Eric, he is on the iPad testing in Safari most likely.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /*styles*/
}
```

I also use `max-width`. What's the difference between `max-width` vs `max-device-width`? The difference, max-device-width only affects those devices that have a max width of XYZpx, so re-sizing a browser window on your desktop would yield no styling changes in relation to that particular media query.  max-width, will yield styling changes on any device/browser that fits the media query. So re-sizing your your desktop browser and having the media query use max-width, you'd see the website as someone using an iPad would.

this is a great reference: [Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)